# Who started the SQL Server Agent?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

How to find out who started the 'SQL Server Agent' in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-CU1) (KB3123299) - 11.0.6518.0 (X64)

Comment: Ask around the office?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Applicationlog ID 102: SQLServerAgent service successfully stopped.
Windows Systemlog ID 7036: SQLServerAgent service successfully stopped.
SQL Server Logs: Event ID: [098] SQLServerAgent service successfully stopped.

It doesn't show who did it. I think you need to configure auditing or tracing for this. For tracing there is a Security Event called [Audit Server Starts and Stops](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189244.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Check in the windows event viewer at that time, you should be able to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the security context under which the SQL Agent service runs? If so, then:

```
SELECT servicename, service_account
FROM sys.dm_server_services;
```